# line seperating uncountable subset of $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory

How to prove that given an uncountable subset $A$ of $R^2$ (which has a subset of uncountable cardinality such that this subset is not lie in any line parallel to x axis ), there exists a line L parallel to x-axis such that the set of points of A  above the line L and set of points of A below the line L both are uncountable.

Comment: Your condition in parentheses shouldn't really be in parentheses, because it's absolutely essential to the proof.

Comment: yes. that is the must condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the opposite and consider the sets $L=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:A\cap\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty;y)$ is countable $\}$ and $U=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:A\cap\mathbb{R}\times(y;\infty)$ is countable $\}$.

Comment: I cant understand your answer. I want a line parallel to x axis dividing A.

Comment: what is the need of U?

Comment: Opps, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: $L \cup U$ is all of $R$. but what is the contradiction?

Comment: Consider a real number $l$ such that $\inf U\le l\le \sup L$.

Comment: what is the contradiction if $l$ is in $U$ or $L$?

Comment: $L \cup U$ is certainly not the whole of $\mathbb R$! That's the whole point.

Comment: In fact we can even choose $l$ to be rational.

Comment: ya. now I understand the contradiction. thanks.